# SSRS adding a blank line to CSV reports

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS report returning the expected number of records when I render the results to HTML.  However, when I export the results to CSV, I notice an extra blank row appended to the end of the results.

Is there a way to eliminate this extra line from the end of my results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alter the rendering extenstion setting for csv export in the RSReportServer.config file. Set the Device Info setting for CSV for ExcelMode to false like this:

```
<Render>
    <Extension Name="XML" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.DataRenderer.XmlDataReport,Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataRendering"/>
    <Extension Name="NULL" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.NullRenderer.NullReport,Microsoft.ReportingServices.NullRendering" Visible="false"/>
    <Extension Name="CSV" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.DataRenderer.CsvReport,Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataRendering">
        <Configuration>
            <DeviceInfo>
                <ExcelMode>False</ExcelMode>
            </DeviceInfo>
        </Configuration>                
    </Extension>
```

The default for the Excel mode setting is true. There is a known bug in the Excel Mode CSV renderer that adds an extra blank line. This workaround will allow you to get around the error. I had to implement this when I moved from SSRS 2005 to SSRS 2008.

Reference: http://w3cgeek.com/blank-lines-at-end-of-ssrs-csv-export.html